# Installation Error While Updating Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I haven't used Eclipse on my Mac in awhile and noticed that I've been using the 2019 software, so I decided to update. However, after going through the motions "check for updates," etc, I get this error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
> session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
> Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,2.0.300.20230130-0743.
> Error reading signed content:/var/folders/9h/m_tpsqy53tl8nswlkgz93lh40000gn/T/signatureFile5179964165581709849.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /var/folders/9h/m_tpsqy53tl8nswlkgz93lh40000gn/T/signatureFile5179964165581709849.jar
> Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.annotations,1.2.0.v20230128-1746.
> Error reading signed content:/var/folders/9h/m_tpsqy53tl8nswlkgz93lh40000gn/T/signatureFile6287758177785589488.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /var/folders/9h/m_tpsqy53tl8nswlkgz93lh40000gn/T/signatureFile6287758177785589488.jar

I tried doing the whole process over again, but got the same error. Any advice of how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: The details of how bundles are signed has changed enough in those 3-4 years that you're better off starting with a fresh download or installation.